# Creating a Custom Android Keyboard with Math Symbols

Tags: android, kotlin, custom-keyboard

I am working on an Android application and need to implement a custom keyboard for mathematical input. The goal is to have a button that allows users to input mathematical symbols such as radicals, fractions, etc., and then be able to edit the content within those symbols. I have explored options like KeyboardView and libraries like MathView, but I'm unsure of the best approach. What are the recommended methods or libraries for creating a custom keyboard with rich text editing capabilities, particularly for mathematical input? Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated

The most important part of this question is that I don't know how to create the things I marked in the picture
[image]